# WCF Service Deployed to Azure (.NET 4) with async Task<T> interface

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, azure, task

I have deployed a WCF service to Azure running in a web role. The Azure is stock standard (so runs .NET 4.0). I am getting the following error:

```
Type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.
```

- My class library targets .NET 4
- I have references to the Async targeting pack

It runs on my local machine via the emulator. My local machine is Windows 8 with .NET 4.5.

It seems to be similar to:
http://forums.lhotka.net/forums/t/11585.aspx

Is this possible, or do I need to get .NET 4.5 on to Azure?

Answer (score 0):

In case the Task is being returned for an Async implementation (which is new in WCF 4.5), this was not supported in .NET 4.0. .NET 4.0 Supports IAsyncResult based Async.

The following applies if the Task was being returned as data (and not for Async):

Does your service returns a Task? That would not be right because a task is some 'work being done' - not 'data' as such. Maybe you tested the process in-proc and therefore it worked?

System.Threading.Tasks.Task is present in .NET 4 too. As the error says, the way your service is written, it needs to serialize a task, which is not possible practically. You should take a  look at your service contract and the data types being used again.

Comment: hrmm, returning a Task from a WCF service is definitely supported in .NET 4.5. 
    //asynchronous:
    [OperationContract(Action = "AppSvcsPing")]
    Task AppSvcsPingAsync();

    Synchronous declaration:
    [OperationContract(Action = "AppSvcsPing")]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ServiceFault))]
    void AppSvcsPing();

Comment: Actually you are right - This is the new Async behavior in .NET 4.5. This is not supported in .NET 4.0. .NET 4.0 supports the older IAsyncResult based service implementations. Upgrading to 4.5 on Azure will instantly solve the issue.

Comment: Sure - I'm wondering if it's absolutely necessary.
Using the async targeting pack, I am able to implement this same approach in .NET 4. It runs on my local machine under .NET 4, so just trying to understand why it won't also work on Azure which is also .NET 4.